# How to open new window from javascript and get value from it on close

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Image in an MVC3 view that, on its click handler, I call an action method using:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    success: function (result) {
      //do Stuff
    }
    });
```

I want to

- Check something on the server, then
- Open a new window, and
- When the user close that window, the parent gets updated with a value from the new window.

I kind of dont know if that is possible, any one has any idea how to do this?

Comment: Stacker - you've **almost** described your requirement above. however, a few more details re what you expect the popup to pass would be useful (i.e. a single form property, a json object etc..). also, would the popup 'save' then be expected to hit an actionresult or merely pass the value to the parent? i'm assuming purely a client update

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
(HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page).ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "winPop",
            "window.open(\"html/???.htm\", \"popup\", \"width=480, height=400\");",
            true);
```